# UserConsentVerifierAvailability enum definitions for Windows 10

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-security, windows-hello

What is the difference between DeviceNotPresent and NotConfiguredForUser properties of UserConsentVerifierAvailability enumeration?

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.ui.userconsentverifieravailability) says "There is no biometric verifier device available" and "A biometric verifier device is not configured for this user", respectively.

From what I understand, DeviceNotPresent is when a pin or Hello hasn't been set up for the user, but what then is NotConfiguredForUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says, the `DeviceNotPresent` is when the machine don't have any biometric authentication capable peripheral device (iris scanner or fingerprint scanner). The value is `NotConfiguredForUser` when the machine have a capable device, but the user haven't configured the Windows Hello yet.